# How to place multiple Text widgets inside a DrawerHeader?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to show multiple lines of text in my DrawerHeader.
Right now, I am doing it with one actual Text widget, which has a string for it's value, that contains multiple "\n" values, to achieve my goal.

I have the following code:

```
Widget _buildDrawer() {
    return ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text(
                _currentUser.displayName + "\n" + "Something 1 \n" + "Something 2", //Here is the problem, I would like to create a custom Text widget for each of these texts.
                maxLines: 3,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white
                ),  
              ), 
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Stúdium jelentkezés'),
              onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app.
              // ...
              // Then close the drawer.
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Koleszhírek'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app.
                // ...
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Profil'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app.
                // ...
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Wrap` widget [official doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html).

```
Wrap(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(...),
    Text(...),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a Column inside the DrawerHeader :

```
        DrawerHeader(
          child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                  Text("One,"),
                  Text("Two,"),
                Text("Three,"),
             ]
           ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not bad. The other answers are also good ways to achieve the same.

But there's one more way to get Something like this:

[image]

Code:

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
  accountName: Text("Name"),
  accountEmail: Text("Description / Mail"),
  currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
    child: Image.network('link to any image')
  ),
  // You can add some more properties
),
```

I hope this answer helped you.